# Подскажите WEB IDE для Ipad

Tags: html, css, ios, ide, ipad

Какая есть хорошая IDE для IPAD, с возможностью редактирования html/css кода, работающая с ftp?

Я понимаю, что оно гуглистся(и я гуглил), но часть платные и требуется с наиболее удобной клавиатурой. Не располагаю временем всё пробовать.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

**Panic** делают хорошие продукты, в частности у них есть хороший редактор под iPad — **[DietCoda](https://panic.com/dietcoda/)**.